# How to properly show computed property on template with vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I want to show my user (which is inside a store) initials only when it's logged in. My template is:

```
<v-menu v-if="this.$store.getters.getLoggedUser">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs, userInitials }">
            <v-avatar v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                {{ userInitials }}
            </v-avatar>
        </template>
</v-menu>
```

Where userInitials is a computed property:

```
computed: {
        userInitials() {
            return this.$store.getters.getLoggedUser.name.split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase()).join('');
        }
    }
```

What I'm getting is an empty string instead of the initials. I tried using the computed property outside of the v-menu tag and it's working fine.

Comment: What is the output of `this.$store.getters.getLoggedUser.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `userInitials` in slot scope deconstruction:

```html
                                      <!--  this is the problem -->
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs, userInitials }">
```

The `activator` slot doesn't have a `userInitials`, so you're overwriting the outer scope `userInitials` with `undefined`.

In short, this will work:

```html
<template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
  <v-avatar v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
     {{ userInitials }}
  </v-avatar>
</template>
```

---

In more detail, a [slot's scope](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) exposes child data to the parent `<template>`. Parent scope members are already available in that template. Anything named in child scope deconstruction will override parent scope members with the same name, even if the child value is `undefined`.

Here's JavaScript equivalent of template slot scope deconstruction:

```js
// outer (parent) scope:
const userInitials = 'something';

function someFunction(args = {}) {
  // inner (child) scope:
  const { on, attrs, userInitials } = args;

  /* in here `userInitials` won't be 'something'. 
   * It'll be `args.userInitials` which, in your case, is `undefined`.
   * If you remove `userInitials` from deconstruction above, you'll 
   * allow access to the outer scope variable.
   * Which is 'something', isn't it?
   */
}
```